# JQUERY If Var is empty

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a form field that can be empty or not.

I'm using the following code to pass the value of the field to **foo**. (note the +)

```
foo = +$('[name=test]').val();
```

I show what is in **foo** on the console

```
console.log(foo);
```

If nothing has been entered in the field, the console shows **0**

If enter a value 123 into the field, then the console shows that value.

With this code if I enter 0 in the form field this still works !

```
    if (foo >= 1) 
    {
   alert (BLAHH);
    }
```

If I enter nothing in the form field then no alert is shown, if I enter 123 the alert is show..

If I enter 0 the alert is show !  Why ?

I've also tried `(if foo != 0)` and  `(if foo !== 0)` and various other combinations. But I get the same result..

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: @Arun Kumar - why have you edited the post ? My line is `foo = +$('[name=test]').val();`

Comment: *"If I enter 0 the alert is show !"* No, it doesn't, not with the code quoted: http://jsbin.com/egoruniw/1

Comment: @JeffVader Oh Oh Sorry Didn't understand your question properly. My mistake.

Comment: ...and the lesson to learn is: don't use silly hacks. If you need a number, write it like this `Number($(...).val())`.

Comment: @thg435: There's no significant difference between that and what the OP has. Other than being more verbose and, I suspect, slower in many engines. (Not that speed is likely to matter.)

Comment: Can you describe what you actually want the code to do?

Comment: @PietDelport OP is trying to convert a string from a text field into a number. The problem is that entering `0` in the field seems to give `true` in `foo >= 1` when converting using `+fieldText`.

Comment: @thg435: LOL, `Number` is *ever so slightly faster* on Chrome and Firefox, in my quick test. Not, again, that it's likely to matter, but that's amusing. http://jsperf.com/plus-vs-number Perfect example of the classic statement about JavaScript: Never guess what will perform better, try it on target engines.

Comment: @Zhihao: That's what the *code* does, but not necessarily what the OP is trying to accomplish. It doesn't help us to suggest improvements to something that isn't necessarily a good approach for what the OP actually wants to get done.

Comment: I have a simple form field. If the user enters a value of 1 or more then the alert should be shown. If they don't enter a value nothing is shown. The issue is if they enter 0, why is it still showing ?

Comment: @PietDelport What OP is trying to *accomplish* is to fix the problem, which is that the observed behavior does not match the intended behavior. The issue seems not to be that OP is trying to accomplish something but doesn't know how, but rather OP is doing something and there appears to be a bug somewhere. What the cause of the problem is though is hard to say at this point, as it doesn't look like we're given the part of the code that causes the bug.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for all the answers. I've re written the entire code on the page so this isn't an issue any more. After thinking about it I feel how I had it was working correctly, but I was in error with what it was doing and how I was expecting it to do it.  So I sat down, looked at what I actually wanted it to do and re wrote it. It's now working. Thanks again.